# How could have vs How could

Tags: grammar, could-modal

> How could we have spent this time on the island?
>
> How could we spend this time on the island?

What is the difference between those two sentences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward: first one is in the past, while the second one is in the present.

In other words, the first phrase sounds almost like a regret: they've already spent the time on the island, and are debating how they could have done it differently.

The second phrase is a common question you ask (yourself) when you first arrive at a destination.

Comment: A group of people have missed the flight toward the island and after some days they said : How could we have spent this time on the island?
Is this sentence correct in this context?

Comment: Yes, because this also refers to a situation in the past. Impossible one, but still.

Comment: What do you mean by "Impossible one, but still"?

Comment: The situation you mentioned. It's impossible to happen because they missed the flight, so they're wondering how they could have spent the time there.

Comment: If we ask someone to guess how we spent the time ,could we say :"How could we have spent this time on the island? "

Comment: Technically, yes, but it would sound too much of an ironic, rhetoric question. You're better off with simply "How did we spend the time on the island?"

Comment: We feel so bored in the island , we spent days of boredom , could someone say : how could we spent all this time in the island ? Is this sentence correct in this context?

Comment: No. In the context "we feel so bored in this island, we have been here for days in complete boredom", you'd have to say "How could we have spent all this time (differently)?"

Comment: could we say "how we were able to spend all this time in the island" ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible too.

Comment: "how we were able to spend all this time in the island" means that the person is surprised how they had the ability to spend the time in the island?

Comment: "How we were able to spend all this time in the island" can be describing how they managed to spend their time there. For a surprising idea, you'd have to invert the pronoun with the verb, as in "How were we able to spend all this time in the island?!"

Comment: *...the second one is in the Present **or Future***. As with *How could men survive on Mars?*

Comment: "How could you do that to me" in this sentence could refers to past situation ?

Comment: I feel like this comment section has become a thread for question-solving, rather than *commenting* itself.

Comment: Is there a difference between "how could I spend this time in this island" and "how I could spend this time in this island"?